# HTML background-size:cover with floating objects

Tags: css

I have a trivial page with body having an image background, with `background-size:cover`. I set `html { height:100% }` to fill up the entire page regardless of the content amount. Up to this point everything worked as expected.

I've added a `div` and set `position:absolute; right:0; width:200px;` This, again, worked as expected, until I added content.

When this div is populated so much that the contents take up more space than the height of the page, the scroll bar appears. Scrolling down reveals that the background image does not actually cover the entire page.

This is due to the fact that my div is taller than 100% of the HTML height.

How can I address this?

Comment: This question is better suited to StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `background-attachment:fixed;` to your `body` element.

The caveat with this approach is that the background is now fixed in the viewport and does not scroll with the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-attachment

Answer (score 0):

Do it like i did in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HwvJm), and it should work fine.

**Update**: (using some JS)

see [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Auqks) for more complete solution.

Comment: Your solution is to tile the background image, but the OP appears to have a single none-repeating background image, so this might not be desirable.

Comment: And the fact that you used my face is really freaking me out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of positioning any items via `position:absolute` I utilized `float` as much as possible.

I also added a `<div>` wrapper to the entirety of contents inside of `<body>` this helps the proper formatting and stretches the containing `<div>` accordingly. The `body` tag and its background properties now behave properly!